# api endpoint returns response 404 - Angular

Tags: angular, laravel-8, angular-services, angular-components, angular11

I have method to save image. Initial `this.educationalData` gives back data in console.log but after that when i try to get `id` from endpoint. It gives me undefined.

**UPDATED** 
it is now sending id of 1 but still respond of 404

```
saveImage() {
  const file = this.imageChangedEvent;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () = >{
    this.apiService.postData('educational-award/' + this.educationalData[0].id, {
      "photo": reader.result,
      "id": this.educationalData[0].id
    }).subscribe(data = >{
      console.log('test')
    });
  };
}
```

**UPDATE** (latest) 
I found out i was using the wrong endpoint. Im sorry for causing trouble to everyone.

```
Route::post('/upload-picture', [UserController::class, 'uploadPicture']);
```

Screenshot to give more clarity

**UPDATED**

[image]

Comment: could you please add an image after opening the arrow of `educationalData` in the console to see the data inside

Comment: oh sure man. give me a sec.

Comment: try `this.educationalData[0].id` or `this.educationalData[0]["id"]`

Comment: yep now it's sending id of 1 now but i get 404 still.

Answer (score 2):

When you build your backend route like this

```
Route::post('/educational-award/{educational_background}',...)
```

you have to put the {educational_background} parameter directly inside the url string and not as a payload parameter. In your case you are passing the id as a payload parameter.

- Why you are getting an undefined for id, that depends on your educationalData object and how the data is constructed in it.
- Update,
  After I have seen your educationalData  it seems that you have an array. So to get the id use `this.educationalData [0].id` .

In your saveImage function use it like this :

```
reader.onload = () = >{
this.apiService.postData('educational-award/'+this.educationalData[0].id, {
  "photo": reader.result,
  "id": this.educationalData.id
}).subscribe(data = >{
  console.log('test')
});
```

Comment: Thanks this gives me id of 1. But im still getting 404 probably my ```this.apiService.postData``` is the problem

Answer (score 1):

The post-endpoint expects a path-param `{educational_background}`. You need to populate it on the client-side:

```
this.apiService.postData('educational-award/'+this.educationalData[0].id, {
  "photo": reader.result,
  "id": this.educationalData[0].id
}).subscribe(data = >{
  console.log('test')
});
```

Comment: yes im passing ```"id": this.educationalData.id``` but i can't get the data because its undefined. That's why post endpoint gives back 404

Comment: You need to pass it as a path-param as well, not only in the body.

Comment: yes i've updated it and copied according to your answer. the payload sends id of 1 and photo but it response to 404 still

Comment: Hm, can you add the server-side code? What does `createEducationalAward` do?

Answer (score 1):

Param {educational_background} is missing

```
this.apiService.postData('educational-award/' + this.educationalData.id, {
```